# Javascript Animation Library for mobile phone HTML5 Canvas Tag

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, game-engine

What is the best JavaScript Animation Library for mobile phone HTML5 Canvas Tag for game development?
Many of the available libraries does NOT provide the required performance for many phone devices.
I tested `doodle.js` and `processingjs`, and normal `setInterval` and `setTimeOut`.
These don't perform as required. The animation stooped for no reasons.
Any suggestion for HTML5 Mobile games canvas Animation?

Comment: Fabric.js can handle animations on most mobile platforms pretty well. Check it out — http://fabricjs.com

Comment: Fabricjs is not fluid on mobile Web  yet. E.g. so slow movement when drag and drop.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend `Collie.js`. Collie is a Javascript library that helps to create highly optimized animations and games using HTML 5. Collie runs on both PC and mobile using HTML 5 canvas and DOM.

http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie

Comment: You might also want to check out the report about the [performance benchmark](http://davidshimjs.github.com/collie-benchmark/)

Answer (score 0):

I have used and highly recommend [**KineticJS**](http://kineticjs.com/).

> KineticJS is an HTML5 Canvas JavaScript framework that enables high performance animations, transitions, node nesting, layering, filtering, caching, event handling for desktop and mobile applications, and much more.

Comment: I'm working with Kinetic on Android 4.2 right now and it's giving me a headache. Many things that work in Chromium do not work in the android mobile browser. E.G. animations are leaving behind artifacts, not starting, the stage is flickering on load, etc...

Comment: Kinetic.js is not fluid on mobile Web, at least not yet.